# How to connect to postgresql in a multithreaded C application

Tags: sql, c, database, multithreading, postgresql

I have a few threads in my application. Each has its own PGconn* connection that is individually opened with the same connection string. When a thread makes a query, it almost never returns PGRES_TUPLES_OK.

I can provide some code examples if necessary, but does anything stand out here? I have tried using global mutexes as well, to no avail. I am using postgresql 9.3

PQerrorMessage(db) returns: connection pointer is NULL

From the postgresql documentation:
    If a null pointer is returned, it should be treated like a PGRES_FATAL_ERROR result. Use PQerrorMessage to get more information about the error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

I was using a function to open each connection, and was passing a pointer to a PGconn struct to it.

I needed to pass a double pointer.